# How to call onUpdate function of widget from network listener service

Tags: android, android-widget

I am building an widget for my app using the vogella tutorials. I am stuck with one doubt.
Whenever the user opens my widget for the first time, My code will call an async which will retrieve data from the web, and in the postExecute it will show the update data into the widget{which is working fine}
After every specified update interval the OnUpdate is called automatically and the async is called again and fresh data is displayed. If in case there is no internet available while updating it uses the previous data and the widget is consistent in this scenario also.

**But if there is no internet connection at the time of widget start[i.e. when the widget is called for the first time] then no data will be visible for that session until the next update interval** [which is 30mins in this widget]

I have added a network listener and it works fine. **But i am not able to call the onUpdate function from the onReceive() of the network listener**.
How can I forcefully call onUpdate function of the widget, static reference wont work in this cade.
please help!
{and sorry for such big text question}

**> Updated Code of Network Listener Class**

```
public class NetworkListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (activeNetInfo != null || mobNetInfo != null) {
        if (!getUpdateComplete(context)) {
            Log.d("NetworkListener", "IsInterruptedDueToNetwork=true");
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                    context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            ComponentName watchWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                    MyWidgetProvider.class);
            (AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)).updateAppWidget(
                    watchWidget, remoteViews);
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

public boolean getUpdateComplete(Context mContext) {
    Log.d("getUpdateComplete", "getUpdateComplete");
    SharedPreferences myPref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Widget",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return myPref.getBoolean("IsUpdateComplete", false);
}
```

}

but still onUpdate method is not called with the above code.
where is my code wrong!

Comment: is your broadcast working

Comment: also how are u calling this broadcast

Comment: I have set it in the Manifest. It should get called whenever network status is changed! {and it is working fine}, but updataeAppWidget never gets called

Comment: where is the logic that will upadte ur widget in OnRecieve..U r not under standing wat I am saying

Comment: No,the code is inside onUpdate of the AppWidgetProvider. I call another async in this Method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the logic to update your widget in onReceive of widget class which can be called any no of time.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.touchwidget);
    watchWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            widget.class);

            if (intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE_WIDGET)) {//user defined action
                //update widget
            }

    (AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)).updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);//it is responsible to update ur widget
}
```

Comment: Great!I will try this in my case.

Comment: Its Not working. Still no call to my onUpdate method. I have updated my question with the code. Please Help!!

Comment: It will not call ur onUpdate ..U need to write to update that u want in OnReceive method

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the OOPs concept then you can not call any protected method directly.. It can be only derived but can not call directly it anywhere you want..

So in your case, `onUpdate()` method is called according the time interval that you have defined  to the widget xml file.minimum interval time is 30 minutes (30*60*100 millis).

You can refer [Android Developer Widget Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) here...

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Thanks for replying; and yes i am aware that my widget will definitely get updated after every 30 mins. but i want it to be updated FORCEFULLY whenever there is network connection available and no previous data available{which will happen if internet not available for the first time when widget is enabled}. I want to know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: Then you need to set interval time to zero and update the view manually using the remotViews... you can refer more about remoteviews on the link that i have given..

Comment: please lead me to any source where it is used, or any link where I can learn doing it.

Comment: refer the link that I have given you in the post... it has stated to update the widget anywhere from your application.